# How to write this request using rawQuery() instead of query() ? (code inside)

Tags: android, database, request

I am trying to write an SQL database request using .query instead of .rawQuery (i have been told it's more efficient, even though not everyone seem to agree with this...).

If I had to write it in SQL, it would be approximately something like this :

```
select COL_NAME, COL_COMMENTS, KEY_ROW_ID   
from TABLE   
where COL_CAT1 = myVariable1 or myVariable2 or ... myVariableN  
or COL_CAT2 = myVariable1 or myVariable2 or .... myVariableN  
or COL_CAT3 = myVariable1 or myVariable2 or.... myVariableN
```

I have tried this :

```
public Cursor findNameInTable(int myVariable1, int myVariable2, int myVariableN) {
    String where = COL_CAT1 + " = ? OR " + COL_CAT2 + "=?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] { Integer.toString(myVariable1), Integer.toString(myVariable2), Integer.toString(myVariableN)};
    c = myDatabase
            .query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, COL_NAME , COL_COMMENTS }, 
                    where,
                    whereArgs, null,
                    null, null);
    return c;
}
```

The problem with this is that the system is doing this :

```
    select .....
    from .....
    where COL_CAT1 = myVariable1 
    or COL_CAT2 = myVariable2
    or ???? = myVariableN
```

and then it crashes because it expects to compare each variable with a new column, which is not what I want: I have more inputs variable than columns.

It's actually the " =?" which seems not to be appropriate, but no way to find how to write this kind of request, most of documentation is about rawQuery() and not query(). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public Cursor findNameInTable(int myVariable1, int myVariable2, ..., int myVariableN) 
{
    String inInterval = "(?,?,?,...,?)"; // N question mark altogether.
    String where = COL_CAT1 + " IN " + inInterval 
                   + " OR " + COL_CAT2 + " IN " + inInterval
                   + ...........
                   + " OR " + COL_CATM + " IN " + inInterval;
int numberOfColumn = M; // The number of columns you have.
String[] whereArgs = new String[M * N];
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
{
     whereArgs[i * N + 0] = Integer.toString(myVariable1);
     whereArgs[i * N + 1] = Integer.toString(myVariable2);
     whereArgs[i * N + 2] = Integer.toString(myVariable3);
        ........................
     whereArgs[i * N + N - 1] = Integer.toString(myVariableN);
}  
Cursor c = myDatabase
        .query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, COL_NAME , COL_COMMENTS }, 
                where,
                whereArgs, null,
                null, null);
    return c;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, there is still a problem with it because it only works when there are as many myVariable as columns (gives me a "bind or column index out of range), and in my application i will have only a few columns and a lot of variables. But anyway, it's better than what I had because it's indeed comparing the value of each column to all the variables!    
I'll try to modify your code a little bit to make it work and fit with my expectations.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely  ! I just found out after some tries and was about to write it here! Nice, thank you so so much for your help, I really appreciate! =)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are creating an extensive query, you may want to consider using:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html

This will allow you to basically create a longer where clause. However; this should also theoretically be possible with a rawQuery with a StringBuilder, but in best practices its better to use the wrapper approach method.